# Excel built in Dialog Box when closing a file

Tags: excel, vba, dialog

I'm referring to [a previous question dealing with macros after closing Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15947082/write-a-macro-in-vba-excel-after-the-user-has-closed-the-excel).

One of the answers gives a quite elegant solution by showing a Dialog Box, created with the simple command "MsgBox".

Now I'm wondering whether an even more elegant solution is possible, by showing the Excel built in Dialog Box (shown when you close a workbook). Purpose: showing a Dialox Box with the same "look and feel" as all other Dialog Boxes, same language, same... .

I've done a little research, but I've only found the Save As Dialog Box.

```
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show
```

After showing the Dialog Box, one obviously needs to obtain the button which has been clicked, to continu the macro in the previous mentioned question.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Reading between the lines, I think that he's asking how you get the value of the button that has been selected. __one obviously needs to obtain the button which has been clicked, to continue the macro__ To my knowledge you can't get the return value by using `Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show`. But you're right @mehow , the question is not very clear

Answer (score 1):

I think what you actually want is `Application.GetSaveAsFilename`

this will display the saveAs dialog box and return back to you the file name if the user selects OK, and False if the user selects X or Cancel.

It should be noted that this just displays the dialog and gets details of the interactions, it will not actually save your file. So you will have to implement this into your code by using the return values.

---

```
Sub test()

Dim ans As Variant
Dim msg As String

ans = Application.GetSaveAsFilename

    If ans = False Then
    msg = "Action was cancelled"
    Else
    msg = "File Path is: " & ans
    End If

MsgBox msg, vbInformation, "Save As Result"

End Sub
```